# Implementing a Java interface method in Scala

Tags: scala

My implementation of a `getHandler` method, which is defined on a Java interface, has failed, and I don't know why. Here is the method signature:

```
<H extends EventHandler> H getHandler( Type<H> type, int index );
```

My implementation in Scala is:

```
def getHandler[H <: com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventHandler]
    (aType: Type[H], index: Int): H 
    = new com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventHandler() {}
```

...but the compiler gives me this message:

```
type mismatch;  
    found: java.lang.Object with com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventHandler
    required: H
```

Where have I erred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may make it compile:

```
def getHandler[H <: com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventHandler]
    (aType: Type[H], index: Int): H = {
  val h = new com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventHandler() {}
  h.asInstanceOf[H]
}
```

It's expecting an `H`. As Lachlan says, `aType` probably is needed somewhere.

Comment: ...and even more succinctly: 
new com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventHandler() {}.asInstanceOf[H]

Comment: It might make it compile, but it is a terrible advice. The code is incorrect, and will cause problems if implemented this way.

Comment: Yes, I agree, as advice it's terrible. I looked at http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java.html and decided that I was just going to answer why it does not compile. I feel bad it's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because your implementation doesn't uphold the contract of the interface. `H` could be *any* subtype of `EventHandler`, determined by the type of the `aType` argument. But your implementation always returns the same anonymous subtype of `EventHandler`, regardless of what is passed as the `aType` argument.

I don't know what a correct implementation would be, but I can't see how this could be implemented without somehow making use of the `aType` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [Lachlan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614498/implementing-a-java-interface-method-in-scala/3614628#3614628) I'd like to point out, that simply casting the return type to the expected type may have desastrous effects.

Consider the following implementation where I have used a named class instead of the anonymous inner class from the question:

```
class MyHandlerA extends EventHandler
class MyHandlerB extends EventHandler

object BadImplementation extends I {
  def getHandler[H <: EventHandler](typ : Type[H], index: Int) = {
    (new MyHandlerA).asInstanceOf[H] // BAD: This asInstanceOf is a lie!
  }
}
```

The following line will cause a `ClassCastException` without warning.

```
val b: MyHandlerB = BadImplementation.getHandler(new Type[MyHandlerB] {} , 0)
```

So in addition to the cast an implementation will have to ensure that the returned handler is actually assignable to H or return `null` or throw an exception.